# how to set tomcat-java to handle large files

Tags: java, tomcat, webtop

I am on Tomcat 6, using VM windows Server 8 64bit, 4gb ram, Xeon 2.6GHz.
tomcat is run as a service.

```
Java Options:
    -Dcatalina.home=C:\Apache\Tomcat 6.0
    -Dcatalina.base=C:\Apache\Tomcat 6.0
    -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Apache\Tomcat 6.0\endorsed
    -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Apache\Tomcat 6.0\temp
    -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Apache\Tomcat 6.0\conf\logging.properties
    -Xms1024m
    -Xmx2048m
    -XX:CompileThreshold=8000
    -XX:PermSize=128m
    -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
    -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
    -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled

Init mem pool: 1024
Max mem pool: 2048
```

Problem:
when retrieving a large amount of files, I get java heap space OutOfMemoryError.

I have read and tried alot of suggestion off post from multiple sites but none have helped.  Any suggestions on to configure for large file transfers??

Just a bit more info may help.  The application i'm using is Documentum Webtop 6.7 sp1.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `when retrieving a large amount of files`? Do you close all associated resources?

Comment: u can use apr for tomcat: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/apr.html

Comment: When doing your large file transfers are you holding the entire contents of the file in memory?

Comment: How big are these files.

Comment: Post the whole OutOfMemoryError output.